# MATLAB on OSX, unbearably slow

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, matlab

My MATLAB running on snow leopard is unbearably slow.

I have tried the `UseQuartz` tweak. That is:

```
$ cat /Applications/MATLAB_R2008a/java.opts 
-Dapple.awt.graphics.UseQuartz=true
```

My start MATLAB settings are: Terminal | Desktop | StartMATLAB

What's going wrong?

**EDIT**

I believe the UI is slow.

```
>> x = bench

x =

    0.2191    0.2952    0.3214    0.4910    0.9205    1.8519
```

Comment: What's slow?  Is it the UI, calculations, plotting, 3D graphics? What does the output of x = bench give you?

Comment: bench on the latest MBP 2011: 0.0870    0.2688    0.1920    0.3071    0.6788    0.8452

Comment: Not sure. From what I've seen, Matlab works quicker on Unix-based OS's. Are your sure your hard drive is not dying or something?

Comment: @Phonon -- How do I test that?

Comment: I have a dual-boot mac. Give it a very busy task that will take several seconds and time it on both OSs. that how I did it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this article](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=2007112503413229):

(1) Make a file called `java.opts` consisting entirely of the line:

```
-Dapple.awt.graphics.UseQuartz=true
```

(2) Place the `java.opts` file at one of the following locations depending on your MATLAB version:

- MATLAB R2007b:  `/Applications/MATLAB_R2007b/java.opts`
- MATLAB R2008a:  `/Applications/MATLAB_R2008a/bin/maci/java.opts`
- MATLAB R2009a:  `/Applications/MATLAB_R2009a.app/java.opts`

(3) Restart MATLAB

This worked for me. I had my `java.opts` file in the wrong spot. Moving it to the right spot fixed the problem.